# IR sensors not working in sunlight

Tags: transistors, comparator

I am using an ITR20001/t optical sensor for a no-touch application.

It is working properly indoors, but if I put the setup in sunlight  the IR receiver is enabling automatically.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Draw a schematic. Both LED and phototransistor require bias and series resistors - of what value? The solution *might be as simple* as reducing the phototransistor load resistor.

Comment: Such a device is not suitable for a situation which is not optically shielded, unless you follow it with an additional circuit seeking a particular pattern in the LED drive.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what sort of signal you are transmitting through the IR LED.  If it's constantly on, then the receiver has no way to distinguish it from sunlight.  They are both constantly on.

Handling sunlight requires something more sophisticated.  Modulate the transmitter by rapidly switching it on and off with a known signal.  A square wave of a few tens of kilohertz is typical.

Then at the receiver end, you need a bandpass filter to eliminate anything that doesn't look like your transmitted signal.  Amplify what is left after that filter.