# I want to detect IR beam of 1064 nm from my rangefinder that will be at least 1200 m away

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, infrared, photosensor

*This question is different from [IR sensors not working in sunlight](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540332/ir-sensors-not-working-in-sunlight) because the principal difficulty is distance and because the sent signal can't be changed in any way*

All the sensors I am using are also detecting sunlight. Is there a way around this? Can I use some other combination of sensors and circuitry to achieve the desired objective?

Just to clarify what I am trying to achieve. I have a laser range finder with a range of 9,000m. I want to train my crew to accurately hit laser on targets that are at least 1km away. To achieve this, I am trying to make a popup target which detects the presence of laser. Sadly I can't do any changes at transmission end at all

My LRF has following specs:

- Laser Type Nd: YAG (1.064 µm)
- Pulse Energy 10 mJ (nominal)
- Pulse Width 10 nSec
- Beam Divergence < 1.0 mRad
- Pulses / min 15 (30 for short time)
- Field of View 2.0 mRad
- Aperture 47 mm
- Range Accuracy + 5m
- Max / Min range 9995 / 200 m
- Range Blanking 200 m – 4000 m
- Range update rate 0.5 Hz (max)
- Magnification X 7
- Field of view 120 mils
- Operating Temp. -30° C to +55° C
- Dimensions 25 x 20 x 11 cm
- Weight 2.2 kg

Comment: Seeing as 1064 nm is part of the spectrum the sun gives us, it isn't surprising that they are detecting sunlight too. Options include: not operating in sunlight, doing some encoding/flashing of your transmission (assuming that the sensor can detect the difference in IR levels), optical fibre to carry the signal, have very directional detectio which will depend on reflections in your enviroment.

Comment: @Finbarr A problem with using modulation alone is that even then it is possible to saturate out and overwhelm the gain before getting a chance to filter on frequency. It works iff the system isn't already railed out by optical flux.

Comment: i can't change the source/ transmitter hence modulation is out of equation. Sunlight is saturating my sensors. is there any way i can get 2 different responses (from sun and from artificial ir) from any ir sensor?

Comment: @defoxtrotalpha Thin film narrow band filters can help. But likely not enough. You will need to use long tubes and baffling and likely also identify polarization modes and anything else unique about your source that you can use. Possibly even spatial (Fourier domain) filtering, as well. Pull out the stops on your imagination! Leave nothing behind.

Comment: Just saying that usually, doing involved optics is harder than living with reduced sensitivity sure to high sunlight background and using a DC-eliminated protocol like everyone designing a few space lights communicating system would do, anyways. The DC average contains no info anyways.

Comment: What is an IRF?

Comment: "Inpatient Rehab Facility" ?

Comment: @defoxtrotalpha. Point to point optical links are mired with many problems as you have already encountered, then with adverse weather conditions (rain and/or hail, fog, polution etc) could become even less reliable. People prefer point-to-point microwave links instead ... but this is probably beyond the scope of your project.

Comment: Are you asking for a sensor which can distinguish between artificial IR and sunlight IR of the same frequency? Because the only way we do that I’m aware of is directionality, which you say you can’t do.

Comment: @defoxtrotalpha Are there any changes at all that you can make at the transmission end? Laser dyes? Diffractive lenses? Anything at all? If not, what exactly are the details of the laser and the kilometer ranged alignment?

Comment: What kind of traffic do you need over this link?

Comment: just to clarify what i am trying to acheive. i have a laser range finder with a range of 9000m. i want to train my crew to accurately hit laser on targets that are at least 1km away. To acheieve this, i am trying to make a popup target which detects the presence of laser. Sadly i cant do any changes at transmission end at all.

Comment: @defoxtrotalpha Sounds very military to me. (An area I once worked in.) But in any case, you could consider a quadrant detector (4 detectors) and arrange things so that the sunlight is evenly distributed (could be done using closed-loop control, if needed, using a thin astigmatic fresnel for example oriented 45 degrees vs the quad and control to the circle of least confusion.) Then, you take the difference of the sum of two diagonally opposite quad pairs which without the laser should be nulled. Once the laser hits, the null is eliminated and detection occurs. Nulls are very sensitive methods.

Answer (score 2):

*Rewritten after OP explains it's a 10 mJ, 10 ns pulse from a rangerfinder's laser*

A kilometre is pretty far for an optical signal likes this.  Consider that a large 12 mm LED at 1200 metres would be 10 *micro* radians, the signal to noise ratio is going to be tiny. However, your flash is short but very bright.  10 mJ in 10 ns would be 1 MW which commenters say is typical for this kind of thing.

As you can't change the source signal at all, you have to find ways to get rid of the noise sources. The main problem, as you say, is sunlight which is strong in the whole IR region.

[image]
*From Newport [Introduction to Solar Radiation](https://www.newport.com/t/introduction-to-solar-radiation)*

So you need **spectral filtering** (remove other wavelengths) and **spatial filtering** (remove other areas).

Of course, make sure the sensor is sensitive at 1064 nm, and note how what else it might be sensitive to.

**First, get as narrow a filter as you can**, to filter out other wavelengths.  You might conceivably need several filters to ensure you don't have anything but 1064 nm coming through.  Here's a curve for a narrow pass filter from a typical optics supplier; pay attention above this range if your sensor has sensitivity there.

[image]
*From [Edmund Optics datasheet](https://www.edmundoptics.com/p/1064nm-cwl-125mm-dia-hard-coated-od-40-5nm-bandpass-filter/39643/)*

**Second, get a telescope**

Do you know where the signal is coming from?  If you do, you can use a telescope to only look at that location.  (If they move, perhaps you can put a GPS on them to find out where they are.)

Telescopes have a recommended maximum magnification, but you can go beyond this as you don't need any resolution.  A good type for this kind of application is the [Maksutov-Cassegrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maksutov_telescope#Maksutov%E2%80%93Cassegrains) because they're very compact and made of mirrors so you don't have to worry about IR blocking except of the eyepiece.  An extra short eyepiece will give more magnification.

For illustration, Saturn has an angular diameter of about 20 minutes = 100 microrad.  Here's a simulation for a typical small MC telescope with a very short eyepiece, which has a field of view of 0.07 degree = 1.2 mrad.  **At a kilometre, the green circle is 1.2 metre wide**.  (Could you even paint this area IR-black?)

You stand a good chance of

[image]
*From [Astronomy Tools](http://astronomy.tools/calculators/field_of_view/) with Bresser - Messier MC-127 - Celestron - X-Cel LX - 2.3mm*

Obviously you'd need to ensure you had an appropriate lens system for 1064 nm.

Consider also:

- If you know the distance to the target exactly, if the trainees get the right answer, they hit the target
- Can you repurpose one of rangefinders to use its detection circuitry? (Ie, put one at the target, interpret whatever signal you can get from it?)
- Can you put a detector near the sending laser, and a wire to the target, so that the detector at the target knows exactly when a 10 ns pulse should arrive?

Comment: @citizen thank you for the copy-edit, but kindly don't change my English spelling to American.

Comment: just to clarify what i am trying to acheive. i have a laser range finder with a range of 9000m. i want to train my crew to accurately hit laser on targets that are at least 1km away. To acheieve this, i am trying to make a popup target which detects the presence of laser. Sadly i cant do any changes at transmission end at all. Is there anything at all that i can do?

Comment: @defoxtrotalpha Could you provide the rangefinder's make & model? It's possible the rangefinder's modulation is available somewhere in its documentation, and you could look for that modulation on the receiver. Very neat idea for training.

Comment: My LRF has following specs:

(Laser Type Nd: YAG (1.064 µm))
(Pulse Energy 10 mJ (nominal))
(Pulse Width 10 nSec)
(Beam Divergence < 1.0 mRad)
(Pulses / min 15 (30 for short time))
(Field of View 2.0 mRad)
(Aperture 47 mm)
(Range Accuracy + 5m)
(Max / Min range 9995 / 200 m)
(Range Blanking 200 m – 4000 m)
(Range update rate 0.5 Hz (max))
(Magnification X 7)
(Field of view 120 mils)
(Operating Temp. -30° C to +55° C)
(Dimensions 25 x 20 x 11 cm)
(Weight 2.2 kg)

Comment: @defoxtrotalpha Could you edit your question: this information belongs there.  What is LRF?

Comment: LRF is laser range finder

Comment: 1 MW pulses is about right for this kind of laser.

Comment: I used a light filter to remove most colors of light.  Then put the receiver in a long black tube trying to remove light coming in from a different direction.  We built a electronic filter that most removed low frequency signals.  We found large signals at 100 or 120hz from outdoor lighting.  So the first stage amplifiers need a high pass filter.  The signal is 10nS so more filtering aiming at 10nS band pass.

Answer (score 2):

The laser light appears as very bright but short flashes of light. @jonathanjo correctly suggests using a narrowband optical filter to remove as much out of band light as possible.

To squeeze the bandwidth smaller - you can use the characteristics of the laser pulse itself. You say the pulses are 10 ns but there will be a repetition rate (usually about 10 Hz). You want a circuit that detects 15 short pulses at the rep rate and rejects signals that don't meet this criteria. (Design a matched filter for this pulse train
)

A telescope at the target might not be useful as this will provide optical gain - at the expense of reducing the number of directions of light that your sensor will respond to.

On the other hand a telescope can work if you place a retro reflector at your target. The telescope is now next to the LRF. Align the optical axis of the telescope to see the field as illuminated by your LRF and if your target is hit then the reflector will return the energy to the telescope. A narrow field of view works in your favour as the less background is seen and you see more laser light. There is also no link required between your target and sensor - you could also temporally gate your sensor so it only works when the LRF is fired - pickoff some outgoing light to trigger it. The filter will work better as narrowband optical filters require collimated light to work well. The disadvantage is that the LRF won't be working in "native mode" as the signal scattered back is now much brighter.

Comment: Those are excellent suggestions.